# Given figure $TP$ and $TS$ are tangents to the given circle

Tags: geometry

In the given figure $TP$ and $TS$ are tangents to the given circle $r$ is point of circumference

[image]

im trying but i could't find any idea and i forget my geometry knowledge please can some help this problem

thank you so much

Comment: 1,2,3 represent equal angles?

Comment: @rhombicosicodecahedron..  i dont know xtacly sir

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$\angle PRS = \angle TPS $ by inscribed angle theorem

$\angle TPS = \angle TQP$ by your definition of $Q$

So, we have $\angle PRS = \angle TQP$ and that means that $TQ||SR$ (corresponding angles)

To prove 7.2 note that $\angle TSP = \angle TPS = \angle TQP$ and so TPQS is inscribed (it is equivalent to $\angle TSP = \angle TQP$)

To prove 7.3  note that we know that TPQS is inscribed, so $\angle TPS = \angle TQS$ (by inscribed angle theorem)

Comment: any idea about other two

Comment: @SURYA, yeah, added those